estimating a proportion from repeated measurements
I'm working on a simple descriptive study of a case series with a rare skin disease. The aim is to describe Vitamin A deficiency in the cohort. We have 12 patients (8 male, 4 female), with a total of 101 Vitamin A measurements (average 8.4 clinic visits per patient). There is a clinical threshold that defines a Vitamin A deficiency, and we have dichotomised the measurements to report the prevalence of Vitamin A deficiency.
A total of 21/101 measurements (20.8%) showed a Vitamin A deficiency. Calculating a simple 95% confidence interval around this proportion assumes the measurements to be independent, which is not quite correct. My question is how can I adjust for the repeated measurements within patient? If I am not mistaken this would only affect the confidence interval but not the estimated proportion, right?
I was thinking about a GEE model with a dichotomous outcome (for example with geeglm in R), which would also allow to adjust for patient sex. Is this appropriate and how can I get the overall proportion and the adjusted confidence interval from such a model?
Thanks for any help.

Unfortunately, your estimate is also affected by the repeated measures. Making 101 measurements from 12 patients, is not the same as making 101 measurements from 101 patients. You need independent measurements to get valid estimators. I am also not sure it is a good idea to dichotomize the measurements; you just have lost a lot of information. Last, trying to adjust for patient sex is theoretically a good idea, but you only 4 female patients; this approaches the bare minimum sample size for any analysis. Sorry, I wish I could share better news...

Many thanks for your response. The problem with rare diseases is that we usually just don't have enough patients for independent measurements. This is an exploratory study, so in the worst case we can just report the raw proportion using all 101 measurements and highlight the limitation of the estimation. Is there any way I can correct for the repeated measurements to report a reasonable prevalence and confidence interval? While it clearly is not ideal to dichotomise the data, it is a very common request by clinician researchers who base their clinical decisions on binary outcomes.

In general, in situations where there is no good analytic solution, bootstrapping is possible. I think it is possible here, but I don't know exactly how I would do it.
